# How to package Node.js app with 'pkg' library when using specific Node.js version (16.14.2)?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to pack a Node.js app into .exe file. I use the Node.js 16.14.2, because the app uses native addons, which work only on this version.

I use this lib: "github.com/vercel/pkg", the last version which is 5.8.1 now. According to manual, the config json looks like this:

```
"pkg": {
        "scripts": "build/**/*.js",
        "assets": "views/**/*",
        "targets": [ "node14-linux-arm64" ],
        "outputPath": "dist"
    }
```

In my case the config looks like this:

```
    "pkg": {
        "target": "--target node16-win32-x64",
        "outputPath": "dist"
      }
```

However, the output says that the lib tries to use Node16.16.0. If I try to explicitly set the version like this:

```
 "pkg": {
        "target": "--target node16.14.2-win32-x64",
        "outputPath": "dist"
      }
```

it gives an error:

> No available node version satisfies node16.14.2

In my system there is only 16.14.2 version. What might be the solution?

I tried to install different Node version - 16.16.0, and tried to set different options in config as described earlier.